# SQL Server 2014 Inner join is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

i have been trying to create an Inner join in SQL SERVER . There is no error in Script but the out put is not correct . 
i have two tables . one is WOPart and other one is PartLocation.common field name is PartPK i would want to achieve Bin number of WOPart(WOPart table primary key number is 10109 which is WOPK) table along with Lot number which is in the PartLocation table.

I have made an inner join

```
SELECT W.PartPK,  P.Lot, W.Bin FROM WOPart W
    INNER JOIN PartLocation P
            ON W.PartPK = P.PartPK
   WHERE  W.WOPK=10109
```

and the out put is

```
4   B1  c2
4   1   c2
7   A   NULL
4   B1  c2
4   1   c2
7   A   NULL
```

out put is not correct because on WOPart table we have four PartPK

```
4
7
4
7
```

BUT post inner join showing six PartPK . PLEASE help me to modify my innerjoin

PartLocation table
[image]

WOPart table
[image]

Comment: The `join` is correct.  You have duplicates in `PartLocation`.

Comment: Could you post the expected result for some input data? Please, add both input data and the expected result.

Comment: in PartLocation table i have three PartPK(4,4,7) but in WOPart table i have four PartPK (4,4,7,7) my requirment is show four partpk from WOpart table along with Lot number from PartLocation table against those matching Partpk.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a distinct select would give you the results you expect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    W.PartPK, P.Lot, W.Bin
FROM WOPart W
INNER JOIN PartLocation P
    ON W.PartPK = P.PartPK
WHERE W.WOPK = 10109;
```

It appears that the `PartLocation` table has two records with a `PartPK` value of `4`.  Hence, the `PartPK=4` entry in `WOPart` is getting duplicated (doubled).